# Highlighting the cell, depending on the text

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet, and in column T, i would like to Highlight the cells, that contain "ok".

I have a code, which works fine with interior.color , but failed to Highlight the cells that contains "OK", instead it is highlighting irrespective of the cell value.

Could anyone suggest, what is wrong with my code ?

```
Sub colour()
Dim totalrows As Long

totalrows = Sheets("S1").Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
With Range("T5:T" & totalrows)
.Value = "OK"
Range("T5:T" & totalrows).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That code does not test for the value of "ok" - where is your IF statement?

Comment: Are you able to perform this with just conditional formatting in Excel?

Comment: I wanted to peform through vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub colour()
    Dim totalrows As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    totalrows = Sheets("S1").Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In Range("T5:T" & totalrows)
        If cel.Value = "OK" Then
            cel.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```